# Проверка позиции ползунка у UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ui

У меня реализован ползунок цены (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) с двумя значениями (мин и макс). Мне нужно проверять, поменялись ли значения у него и если да - добавлять класс .custom родителю (.main-box) и как только значения вернулись в исходную позицию - удалять класс .custom у .main-box.

Вот мой код:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-box">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="price2" id="price2">
    </div>
    <div id="slider_price"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $("#slider_price").slider({
      range: true,
      //orientation: "vertical", 
      min: 100,
      step: 3,
      max: 700,
      values: [100, 700],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        //$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        $('#price').val(ui.values[0]);
        $('#price2').val(ui.values[1]);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону событий, тут вероятно подойдет stop

[Пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webtrump/ds54s75u/)

```html
<style>.custom input{font-weight:bold; color:red; border-radius:5px}</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-box">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="price2" id="price2">
    </div>
    <div id="slider_price"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $("#slider_price").slider({
      range: true,
      //orientation: "vertical", 
      min: 100,
      step: 3,
      max: 700,
      values: [100, 700],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        //$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        $('#price').val(ui.values[0]);
        $('#price2').val(ui.values[1]);
      },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    //$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    var min = $("#slider_price").slider("option", "min");
    var max = $("#slider_price").slider("option", "max");
    if(ui.values[0]==min && ui.values[1]==max){
    $('.main-box').removeClass('custom');
    } else {
    $('.main-box').addClass('custom');
    }
  }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это оно!

Ещё как вариант можно просто сравнивать 2 значения через if.

if(ui.values[0] ==  || ui.values[1] < 700) {
  $('.filter-price').addClass('l-border'); 
} else {
  $('.filter-price').removeClass('l-border'); 
}

Comment: мне кажется лучше тянуть из самого слайдера, именно из опций, значения мин и макс, так не надо что у вас в условии 700 или 1000 или 5000.

Comment: Да, верно, так правильно.